# Suppose $P(X \in B) \in \{0,1\}$ for all $B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Show $X = c$, $P$-almost-surely.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathcal P)$ be a probability space and let $X$ be a random variable.

Suppose $P(X \in B) \in \{0,1\}$ for all $B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

I want to show that there exist $c \in \mathbb R$ such that $X = c$, $P$-almost-surely.

For this I've tried the following:

I guess, I should prove $P_X = \delta_c$ where $\delta = \inf\{ t \in \mathbb R : F_X(t) =1\}$ where $F_X(t) = P(X \le t)$.

However, I haven't been able to do this using my comtemporary knowledge.

Please advice.

Comment: Resnick calls this condition "Almost trivial", and proves that lemma here:  https://books.google.com/books?id=T9-PMDSVDNsC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=almost+trivial+random+variable&source=bl&ots=lnOZgGNMig&sig=UdUwLjoeRFiVNSFOuMI3LlXGc4w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FOWOVLn8NMW1ggSmmILQDg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=almost%20trivial%20random%20variable&f=false

Comment: By the way, in probability theory we generally say "almost surely" instead of "almost everywhere."

Comment: Why does the jump of $1$ at $c$ imply $P(X=c) = 1$ ?

Comment: I mean, it could be that $F_X(c) = P(X \le c) = 0$, right ?

Comment: No, that could not be. Hint: **càdlàg**.

Answer (score 2):

It follows another approach.

I claim that there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{P}[X \in B_{\varepsilon}(y)]=1$, for every $\varepsilon >0$. Indeed, if this is not the case, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we can find $\varepsilon_x>0$ with $\mathbb{P}[X \in B_{\varepsilon_x}(x)]<1$. Then, by hypothesis, $\mathbb{P}[X \in B_{\varepsilon_x}(x)]=0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$ Writing down $\mathbb{R}$ as a countable union of balls of this kind we can conclude that $\mathbb{P}[X \in \mathbb{R}]=0$, a contradiction.

But $\mathbb{P}[X \in B_{\varepsilon}(y)]=1$ implies $\mathbb{P}[|X-y|>\varepsilon]=0$, $\forall \varepsilon >0$. Then $X=y$ almost surely.

Answer (score 0):

With $c=\inf\{\,t\in\mathbb R:F_X(t)=1\,\}$ (why is $c$ finite, i.e. neither $+\infty$ nor $-\infty$?) we have $$\begin{align}P(X\ne c)&= P(X\le c-1)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(c-\tfrac1n< X\le c-\tfrac1{n+1})\\&\quad +\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(c+\tfrac1{n+1}\le  X< c+\tfrac1{n})+P(X>c+1)\\&=\underbrace{F_X(c-1)}_{=0}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigl(\underbrace{F_X(c-\tfrac1{n+1})-F_X(x-\tfrac1n}_{=0-0})\bigr)\\&\quad +\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigl(\underbrace{F_X(c+\tfrac1{n})-F_X(x+\tfrac1{n+1}}_{=1-1})\bigr)+(1-\underbrace{F_X(c+1)}_{=1})
\\&=0\end{align}$$

Comment: why can't $c$ be equal to $\infty$ ?

Comment: you can use tightness. $\lim_{t \to -\infty}F_X(t)=0$ implies there exists some $b$ such that $F_X(b)=0$.